# Simulation of integral to infinity

Tags: mathematical-statistics, simulation, monte-carlo, integral

I need to estimate an integral that has the next form:

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{q_\alpha}^\infty S(x)dx$$ where $S(x)=1-F_S(x)$,
$\epsilon$ is close to $1$.

The value $q_{\alpha}$ is a quantile at level $0.99$. This expression is considered for the case of light tailed distributions. I was thinking about to perform a Monte Carlo estimation using 
$$\frac{1}{N\epsilon}\sum_{j=0}^N S(x)$$
But I dont have clear about how to select $N$, I don't have also a expression for $S$ I was simulating that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

The estimator$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^N S(x_j)$$is an approximation of the integral$$\int S(x)f(x)\text{d}x$$where $f$ is the density of the $x_i$'s. Conversely, if one wants an approximation of $$\int S(x)\text{d}x$$ with simulations from $f$, one should use the estimator$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^N \frac{S(x_j)}{f(x_i)}$$which is a form of importance sampling ($f$ and $F$ are not related with the same distribution).

In the specific case of the question, simulating random variables from $F_S$ is not efficient since $99\%$ of the simulations will be rejected. An importance function $f$ concentrated on $(q_a,\infty)$ should be used instead.